# How to identify a thread uniquely in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there any way, in Java, to identify uniquely a thread? Using only `Thread.getCurrent().getId()` isn't enough since a thread may die and the next one might get its ID. For me, those aren't the same threads so I need a way to identify them.

The thread creation time stamp would be useful, if I can get it.

Comment: Have you considered using the thread object itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's wrong with using `==`? Or if you need an actual number, [`System.identityHashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29) is probably a safe bet.

Comment: Didn't even think about that!